# How to implement steam auth into nuxt

Tags: node.js, express, steam, nuxt.js

There is a ready site on nuxt. I'm looking for a way to implement authorization. I found the package for authorization using express.js [steam-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/steam-login), everything works .. How now routing `/login / logout` and the like to get to work and how to use the received data about the user in nuxt when rendered? I tried with middleware but nothing happened. Thank you.

There are example of getting data

```
app.use(steam.middleware({
realm: 'http://localhost:3000/', 
verify: 'http://localhost:3000/verify',
apiKey: "api key"}));

app.get('/authenticate', steam.authenticate(), function(req, res) {
res.redirect('/');});
```

and there we can use nuxt builder, I did not find a way to transfer this data to nuxt and use it in the template. And routs nuxt overlap routs express

```
const nuxt = new Nuxt()
nuxt.build()
  .then(() => {  
    app.use(nuxt.render)
    app.listen(3000)})
```

Comment: As @Simo says, please provide an example of your attempt. Also the `steam-login` module is for the server side, so see https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/

Comment: i'm add some information, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solved this problem with serverMiddleware.

Added new custum middleware into nuxt.config

```
serverMiddleware: [
   '~/api/index'
]
```

app.use(require('express-session')({ resave: false, saveUninitialized: false, secret: 'a secret' }));

```
app.use(steam.middleware({
   realm: 'http://localhost:3000/', 
   verify: 'http://localhost:3000/login/verify',
   apiKey: "apiKey"}
));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.user == null ? 'no user' : req.user).end();
});

app.get('/authenticate', steam.authenticate(), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/login/');
});

app.get('/logout', steam.enforceLogin('/'), function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});


module.exports = {
    path: '/login/',
    handler: app
};
```

And with axois in my template get this data from /login route. Thanks

Comment: Do you still have this solution?